# Capture click events on React Native with RxJS

Tags: react-native, rxjs

There are many examples on the internet, like [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md), that show how to capture a click event in a web page with RxJS.

I tested these examples and they all work fine, even in React.js applications, but they don't work on **React Native** applications because React Native applications don't have a DOM.

Is there a way to capture click events with **RxJS** using `Rx.Observable.fromEvent` in a **React Native** applications? (not React.js)

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Answer (score -2):

one possible solution is using Subject to do this in the OnPress function and subscribe it on the ComponentDidMount function and here is a quick sample (also available [here](https://gist.github.com/aaronisme/14c71847f043d73869d7a91ee8d6612e)). hope it will be helpful.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.subject = new Subject();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     this.subject.subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.error(err))
  }

  onPress =(item) => {
    this.subject.next(item)
  }

  render() {
    return (<View>
        <Button onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>)
  }
}
```